# jQuery | Can I Run Speceific Code Based On What An Images Average Color Is?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have had trouble finding any examples of this so I thought Id ask here hoping to get a better idea on whether this is possible or not. What I want to do is have images being dynamically grabbed from a feed. Based on the images' average color is (or even better what color the image would look like if it were only a few pixals big) run a specific code that puts that images somewhere in a picture that will be built out by these images that are pulled. Would I need jQuery for this or the canvas tag maybe?

Any help or insight on how I could begin to make this possible would be excellent!

Thanks :)

Comment: just resize to 1 px and get the color of that pixel.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a good solution for you, it gets the predominant color in a image, so from that you could execute your code.

https://github.com/briangonzalez/jquery.adaptive-backgrounds.js